# Find a substring in block of text, unless it is part of another substring

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was looking for an efficient way to find a substring between two expressions, unless the expression is a part of another.

For example:

> Once upon a time, in a time far far away, dogs ruled the world. The End.

If I was searching for the substring between **time** and **end**, I would receive:

> in a time far far away, dogs ruled the world. The

or

> far far away, dogs ruled the world. The

I want to ignore if **time** is a part of **Once upon a time**. I didn't know if there was a pythonic method without using crazy for loops and if/else cases.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Could you clarify the desired output?  You want the maximal (greedy) match, or the minimal match?

Comment: I would want 'far far away, dogs ruled the world. The' (minimal one) @wim

Answer (score 2):

This is possible in regex by using a negative lookahead

```
>>> s = 'Once upon a time, in a time far far away, dogs ruled the world. The End.'
>>> pattern = r'time((?:(?!time).)*)End'
>>> re.findall(pattern, s)
[' far far away, dogs ruled the world. The ']
```

With multiple matches:

```
>>> s = 'a time b End time c time d End time'
>>> re.findall(pattern, s)
[' b ', ' d ']
```

Comment: Are we trying to find the innermost "time..end" or just avoid the phrase "Once upon a time?" The question implied the latter, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not sure.  I thought the former seemed a more practical use-case.  I guess we leave both answers here for future readers ...

Answer (score 1):

Just remove 'Once upon a time' and check what's left.

```
my_string = 'Once upon a time, in a time far far away, dogs ruled the world. The End.'
if 'time' in my_string.replace('Once upon a time', ''):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution here is to use capturing and non-capturing regular expression groups. Since regex alternations get parsed from left to right, placing any *exceptions* to the rule first (as a non-capture) and end with the alternation that you want to select for.

```
import re

text = "Once upon a time, in a time far far away, dogs ruled the world. The End."
query = re.compile(r"""
  Once upon a time|            # literally 'Once upon a time',
                               # should not be selected
  time\b                       # from the word 'time'
  (.*)                         # capture everything
  \bend                        # until the word 'end'
""", re.X | re.I)

result = query.findall(text)
# result = ['', ' far far away, dogs ruled the world. The ']
```

You can strip out the empty group (that got put in when we matched the unwanted string)

```
result = list(filter(None, result))
# or result = [r for r in result if r]
# [' far far away, dogs ruled the world. The ']
```

and then strip the results

```
result = list(map(str.strip, filter(None, result)))
# or result = [r.strip() for r in result if r]
# ['far far away, dogs ruled the world. The']
```

This solution is particularly useful when you have a number of phrases you're trying to dodge.

```
phrases = ["Once upon a time", "No time like the present", "Time to die", "All we have left is time"]
querystring = r"time\b(.*)\bend"
query = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, phrases)) + "|" + querystring, re.I)

result = [r.strip() for r in query.findall(some_text) if r]
```